# Read file till special char, copy that section into another file, and continue till eof

Tags: linux, shell-script, split

I am trying to read a file in Linux and as soon as a "&" character is encountered, I am writing the output to another file, sending that file to another folder and then continuing to read the original file till next "&" and so on

Input xml file-

```
<Document>
<tag1>
<tag2>
</Document>
&
<Document>
<tag3>
<tag4>
</Document>
&
<Document>
<tag5>
<tag6>
</Document>
```

My code snippet -

```
while IFS= read -r line;do
     if [["$line" =="$delimeter"]];then
         echo "$line" | sed "s/delimeter.*//">> "$output_file"
         cp "$output_file" "$TARGET_FOLDER" 
         break
     else
         echo "$line" >> "$output_file"
     fi
done < "$input_file"
```

However, the code is producing the entire file as the output instead of splitting by occurrence of delimeter, can I please be directed towards where I'm going wrong?

Expected Output -
The first `<Document> to </Document>` (till &) section is put in output file, which is copied to TARGET_FOLDER. Then the next `<Document> to </Document>` section is copied and so on.

Thankyou for your help!

Comment: Is it XML or HTML?

Comment: Hi, it is XML..

Comment: Can you share a valid XML sample with closing nodes? I will share how to parse XML properly. And add your expected output. Please, [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/758623/edit) your post accordingly. Tools to parse XML in a shell: xidel, xmlstarlet, xmllint

Comment: Hi Gilles, correct me if I'm wrong, but do we need xmlparser here? Is there no way to just read till the character "&", and copy that text to another file?

Comment: We don't have sufficient information, I made recommendations

Comment: Added after editing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149050/discussion-between-python6-and-gilles-quenot).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a job for `csplit`:

```
mkdir -p target &&
  csplit -f target/output. your-file '/^&$/' '{*}'
```

Would create `target/output.00`, `target/output.01`... files, splitting on lines that contain `&`.

If you just want one `target/output` file with the `&` lines removed, then that's just:

```
grep -vx '&' < your-file > target/output
```

Or if it's to send to an `output` file in `target.xx` directories:

```
csplit -f '' -b target.%02d/output your-file '/^&$/' '{*}'
```

Though note that the `target.00`..`target.n` directories must exist beforehand.

In any case, [you don't want to use a shell loop to process text](/q/169716).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help, the first suggestion from you is only generating one output file - output.00

Comment: @python6 then the delimiter line likely contains not only `&`. Maybe it has whitespace or invisible characters around it such as a CR character if it comes from the Microsoft world, and you'd need to adapt the regexp (`/^&$/`) accordingly (like `/^[[:space:]]*&[[:space:]]*$/` to allow any amount of whitespace including CR characters on either side of the `&`).

Comment: great, works now

Answer (score 0):

With `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS="&"}{print $0 > ++c".xml"}' file.xml
ls -ltr
```

Comment: This may break on things like `&amp;` occuring elsewhere in the input.